# How to add Shift+Enter and Shift+Ctrl behaviour to a button in Captivate 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-captivate

I'm trying to create a Shift+Enter button and a Shift-Ctrl` button in Captivate 8. I would like to use JavaScript so I can publish both as SWF and HTML5. I've looked at some JavaScript but it doesn't seem to work.